# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch reactjs

Tags: reactjs, cors

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch ReactJS

I tired to change code into,

```
 headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    'mode':'no-cors',
  },
```

Error will be show in localhost,

api url from origin 'http://localhost:3000' **has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.**

**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch**

Answer (score 0):

you are fetching data via node js ? Usually you need to allow CORS in the backend

Comment: my backend is Laravel. how to solve the problem?